# Any way to carry the gapi.client object on multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I want to have two flows where in on the first page I just ask the user to signin.
Then if he/she wants to invite friends, I want to fire the `gapi.client.people.list` method and retrieve the visible circle list.
As I am doing this on two seperate pages, I am not able to carry through the gapi object which has been authenticated. I don't want to trigger the signin flow again but if I directly do `gapi.client.load`, it gives me an error saying `Daily unauthenticated usage limit exceeded`.

```
function getFriends(e)
{

    gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
            //gapi.client.setApiKey("myKey");
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({
                    'userId': 'me',
                'collection': 'visible'
            });
            request.execute(function(people) {
                    console.log(people);
                    $('#googleFriends').empty();
                    $('#googleFriends').append('Number of people visible to this app: ' +
                            people.totalItems + '<br/>');
                    for (var personIndex in people.items) {
                            person = people.items[personIndex];
                            $('#googleFriends').append('<img src="' + person.image.url + '">');
                    }
            });
    });
}
```

Is there a solution here? I tried using `gapi.client.setApiKey` but that keeps returning an `invalid key error`.
I have read and tried to understand google quickstart tutorial but there they call the `people.list` as part of signin flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user already signed-in/authorized your app, you can use the `gapi.auth.authorize` method with the same `client_id` and `scope` parameters you have used for the Sign-in, and `immediate` set to `true`.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
  client_id: 'your_client_id',
  scope: 'your_scopes',
  immediate: true
}, function (authResult) {
  // check authresult and then call getFriends
});
```

This will go through the auth process without any user interaction necessary and `gapi.client` will then be able to make authorized calls. You will have to check the response in the callback though, to make sure you are actually authorized.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize

Comment: So button click should trigger `gapi.auth.authorize`. Do I need `gapi.client.load` at all. Pardon my naivety if it's obvious

Comment: Yes, you need to call `gapi.client.load` which loads the API specific methods, otherwise you won't be able to call `gapi.client.plus` methods.